# Get 18-99 range instead of 0-100 range

Tags: java, android, math, kotlin

I'm implementing a custom `SeekBar` (RangeBar). I've successfully created it and can detect the "thumb" value when I drag it by finding the relative X coordinate of the thumb in its parent as a percentage:

```
val minimumAge = (leftThumb.x / parent.width * 100)
```

So this gives me a value between 0 and 100.

However, I would like the minimum value to be `18` and the maximum value to be `99` (while keeping the same x ratio)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the calculation like this

```
val minimumAge = (leftThumb.x / parent.width * (99-18)) + 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate the value using

```
(99 - 18) * value / 100 + 18)
```

or if you want to use double and then round

```
Math.round((99 - 18) * value / 100.0) + 18
```

Answer (score -1):

Transform your 0-100 bar ratio to a 0-81 (99 - 18) ratio, then add 18 to enforce your minimum value range.

```java
val minimumAge = 18 + (leftThumb.x / parent.width * 81)
```

Comment: `(leftThumb.x / parent.width * 100)`, this will be between 0 and 100. Now what is 100/81 roughly?

Comment: Yikes, that was dumb of me. So if `(leftThumb.x / parent.width * 100)` gives OP 0-100, then `(leftThumb.x / parent.width * 81) ` gives them 0-81 right? Then add 18 and we get 18-99?